# What is the correct way to use the ternary operator with React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently using this code:

```js
      render: props.columnLinks[key]
        ? ((text): ReactElement => <a href={props.columnLinks[key]}>{text}</a>)
        : undefined,
```

but I would like to simplify the statement using the `&&` operator. When I do this however, Typescript throws errors including:

```
Type 'false' is not assignable to type '((text: any, record: TableDataPoint, index: number) => ReactNode) | undefined'
```

How is it possible to structure this as you would be able to in JavaScript?

Comment: What's the value of props.columnLinks[key]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the ternary? Conditional rendering?

Comment: Thanks, if `props.columnLinks[key]` is not undefined I would like the `render:` object property to have the value: `((text): ReactElement => <a href={props.columnLinks[key]}>{text}</a>)`

Comment: @Train it can be undefined or a string.

Comment: You can also use conditional spread: `{ ...columnLinks[key] && { render: text => <a href={columnLinks[key]}>{text}</a> } }`

Answer (score 2):

Your ternary is failing because when your condition isn't met, you're setting a property to `false` rather than your expression.

You might get some benefit from [reading the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) -  React has some of the more common techniques explained with simple code examples. At the very least, it might help you narrow down your definitions on questions like this, or realize that your approach to conditional rendering isn't the path of least resistance!

In JavaScript, `true && expression` always evaluates to `expression`, and `false && expression` always evaluates to `false`. Put another way - Your expression will only be evaluated if it's on the right of the ternary operator. In this case, your type (`((text: any, record: TableDataPoint, index: number) => ReactNode) | undefined'`) cannot be `false`. When you try to set it to `false`, TypeScript rightly alerts you that this is not allowed.

If your goal is conditional rendering, you could move logic into the HTML? Otherwise, I'd handle your null checking elsewhere so you can have more control on what that property evaluates to.

Comment: Thanks @R. McManaman - I am actually trying to make this conditional assignment in a straight javascript factory function where I assign object properties, and in this case I want the assignment to be conditional. It just so happens that what should be assigned to the property is a React element. It will be a property of an object that is passed as a prop. My issue is that I don't need the two branches of the ternary operator, just to be able to assign this property if the condition is truthy.
I have tried re-writing it like this but it still doesn't work, can you suggest anything? :

Comment: `const linkElement = props.columnLinks[key] !== undefined && ((text: string): ReactElement => <a href={props.columnLinks[key]}>{text}</a>)`
...
`render: linkElement`